# Key codes: xterm vs. Terminal.app

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I mostly use iTerm, and it lets you customize the key codes sent to your terminal by individual keys. It has a couple presets labeled `xterm Defaults` and `Terminal.app Compatibility`. I'd like to make my setup as portable as possible (I have some Vim configuration that depends on particular key codes). Will going with Terminal.app compatibility compromise portability to other 'nix systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you use the terminal. [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com) (are you using **[iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/)**?  I have both and neither came with additional profiles) in a quick check using [tack](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/tack.html) is providing function keys using xterm-style encoding for shift- and control-modifiers.  Terminal.app does none of that.  For the ones where it does send something, it is different, and mostly it sends nothing at all.  You are probably better off using iTerm's profile for xterm.